# Enable BT from a Service do not works on Android 14

Tags: android

I'm trying to show the enable BT dialog from a service using this command

> startActivity(new
> Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));

but the dialog isn't displayed even if I add the

> 

to the Manifest.

Is there a way to enable the Bluetooth from a Service in A14 or higher?

Comment: i am also facing same issue, Did you find solution.